# Перевод const char* в const u_char*

Tags: c++, c, указатели, const

Я работаю с двумя функциями из сторонних библиотек. Одна возвращает `const char*`, а другая принимает `const u_char*`. Изменить функции не представляется возможным.
Я пробовал использовать `static_cast<>()` и `reinterpret_cast<>()`, но такое преобразование является некорректным. Как и преобразование простым приведением типов в стиле Си. 
Как следует поступить в моей ситуации?

Ошибки ещё во время компиляции:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type 'const char*' to type 'const u_char* {aka const unsigned char*}'
const u_char* pbuf = static_cast<const u_char*>(buf);
```

Comment: Уточните, какое преобразование в вашем случае следует считать корректным? К примеру, `0 => 0` или `-127 => 0`?

Comment: Какой компилятор? В g++ `const u_char* pbuf = (const u_char*)(buf);` прекрасно компилируется

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит о того, что вы называете корректным, следующий код компилируется и выводит строку:

```
void foo(const unsigned char* str) {
  cout << str; // Test string
}

int main() {
  const char *str = "Test string";
  foo(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(str));
  return 0;
}
```